# What does "the decidedly inauthentic modern Steinway" mean here?

Tags: meaning

An example under the entry "inauthentic" in Oxford Dictionary:

> not genuinely belonging to a style or period:
>
> baroque harpsichord pieces played on the decidedly inauthentic modern Steinway

What does "the decidedly inauthentic modern Steinway" mean here?

Does it refer to a Steinway piano?

Does it mean the piece of music is not suitable for modern pianos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does refer to the piano.  *Decidedly* means definitely or without a doubt- inarguably.  It's saying that because a Baroque harpsichord piece was intended to be played on a harpsichord of the Baroque era, playing that piece on a "modern" Steinway piano would definitely not be an authentic rendition.